# About Meta XR Simulator not showing up in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, unity-xr

**Goal**

I imported Meta XR Integration package and Meta XR Simulator. Project platform is Android.

At play mode I want to show Meta XR Simulator window.

**Content**

I use Built-in and Unity2022.3.8f1. I am using Meta XR Integration 57.0 and Meta XR Simulator 57.0.

[Meta XR Simulator Package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/goilu.png)

I tried for show up Meta XR Simulator window from some community and forum but it is not working.

[Meta XR Simulator Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxTrt.png)

**Tried Reference URLs**

https://communityforums.atmeta.com/t5/Unity-VR-Development/About-Meta-XR-Simulator-not-showing-up/td-p/1036314

https://forum.unity.com/threads/xr-device-simulator-does-not-work-properly.1338665/

**Source URLs**

-Meta XR Integration

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/oculus-integration-deprecated-82022

-Meta XR Simulator

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/meta-xr-simulator-synthetic-environment-builder-269799

[Git URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSTWL.png)

com.meta.xr.simulator@57

Comment: Pardon me, but what, exactly, is the problem?

Comment: At play mode I want to show Meta XR Simulator window.

Now Meta XR Simulator window not showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.Tick the Option:**

Please tick this option in project setting.

*Edit > Project Settings > XR Plug-in Management > Windows, Mac, Linux*

[image: Setting Image]

**2.Active Simulator PowerShell**

Please execute <activate_simulator.ps1> file with PowerShell.

*{ProjectName}\Library\PackageCache\com.meta.xr.simulator@57.0.0\MetaXRSimulator\activate_simulator.ps1*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Same error, now solved!!!

Meta XR Simulator -> activate actually change the default OpenXR Runtime in regedit table. you can read the script at \Library\PackageCache\com.meta.xr.simulator@62.0.0\MetaXRSimulator\activate_simulator source code.

But, sometimes it just fails to change the regedit table !!!

So, I change regedit table manually !!! like image below, it just works!!!

Remember, backup the original ActivateRuntime value and change it back when you do not use simulator, but use device or steam VR maybe.

[image]